# How much of the plane is 4-colorable?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, graph-colorings

In 1981, [Falconer](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316581900145) proved that the measurable chromatic number of the plane is at least 5. That is, there are no measurable sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, each avoiding unit distances, such that $\bigcup_i A_i=\mathbb{R}^2$. Last week, [de Grey strengthened this result](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385), removing the requirement of measurability.

I would like a quantitative version of Falconer's result. For any measurable $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, define

$$
\overline\delta(A)=\limsup_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\operatorname{vol}(A\cap[-T,T]^2)}{\operatorname{vol}([-T,T]^2)}.
$$

**Question:** What is the supremum $m$ of $\overline\delta(\bigcup_i A_i)$ over all measurable $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ that avoid unit distances?

I am interested in both lower and upper bounds.

**Motivation:** [Polymath16](https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2018/04/14/polymath16-first-thread-simplifying-de-greys-graph/) is attempting to find 5-chromatic unit-distance graphs with few vertices. By modifying a result of Pritikin (Lemma 1 [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895698918196)), one may show that every unit-distance graph with fewer than $1/(1-m)$ vertices is 4-colorable. As such, good estimates of $m$ would indicate how small our graphs can be.

Here's what we currently know:

- The proof of [Pritikin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895698918196)'s Theorem 4 provides explicit $A_i$ to demonstrate $m\geq0.9174$.
- [Heule](https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2018/04/14/polymath16-first-thread-simplifying-de-greys-graph/#comment-3867) found a 5-chromatic unit-distance graph with 826 vertices, implying $m\leq 1-\frac{1}{826}$.

*(Warning: Pritikin reports a lower bound of 0.919 after multiplying by 4 incorrectly. Also, it is not clear to me what his explicit construction is, as I don't have access to Croft's paper. I assume the construction uses $A'$ instead of $C'$.)*

Presumably, there are other (linear programming?) approaches to obtain upper bounds.  For related work, distance-avoiding sets in the plane seem to have received a bit of attention; [see this survey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=8F6A67AFCBDAB161827B5D53FFA1009B?doi=10.1.1.642.8688&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Coloring a near penny packing (using pennies of diameter less than 1 and leaving enough space) probably gives the .919 lower bound.  Anyone try substituting Reuleaux Triangles or other constant width object packings?  Gerhard "Shaping Up A Lower Bound" Paseman, 2018.04.18.